# Is Meteor.JS class-based events safe?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

*Note: the example beneath is just a fictional and simplified example!*

Say that I have two buttons in a Meteor.JS app: one to agree, which adds +1 to a score of a certain element, and one to disagree, which substracts one of a certain element.

If I use class-based events for this (so one to agree, one to disagree), is it possible for a user to manually change the class and overrule conditions set in the template?

```
<button class="agreement tiny">

 Agree!

</button>
```

If the user clicks on this button, he gets the possibility to remove his agreement:

```
<button class="remove-agreement tiny">

 Remove agreement!

</button>
```

My question is whether it is possible for a user to manually change the class of the remove-agreement button from `remove-agreement`to `agreement`, so that he can add multiple +1s. Is this possible? I've tried it myself and it doesn't seem to work, but I'm (obviously) no expert at this.

EDIT: it does work now. Does this mean I need to implement server-side security for this?

Comment: Never trust data sent by the client, they can easily trick your server into assuming the client clicked on a button that is hidden or that he shouldn't be allowed to click... what if they read your code and discover what Meteor method is being called and decide to call it directly from browser console ? Implement a user-based system to be secure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the user can remove the class. I do this every time a website asks to give a Facebook Like. It's 10 seconds to remove the `display:none`. 10 seconds for privacy is ok for me.

Every time a clients asks to insert/update/remove something, you need to validate this.

This is have obvious scenario: you need to store the user vote and every time the user tries to vote/down vote you check if the users has already voted. If for reason the user is trying to vote down or up more than 1 time you can log this, analysing and decide if you should ban the user.

You can use the [allow/deny rules](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) to check this or even a [simple server method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/methods_header). Don't forget to check/block the database CRUD operations that come from the client otherwise... you're screwed!